# Running multiple docker containers from one image with different teamcityagent names

Tags: docker, teamcity

I tried to do what is mentioned in: [Multiple Docker containers, same image, different config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980547/multiple-docker-containers-same-image-different-config)

I did:

```
docker run --name DockerAgent1 <same image id>
docker run --name DockerAgent2 <same image id>
docker run --name DockerAgent3 <same image id>
```

But then I get the error:

```
Agent id=<unknown>. Another agent with name "DockerAgent"(id=173) is registered on the server. Please check you do not have two agents with the same name.
```

In teamcity I only see DockerAgent under unauthorized.

Also in my dockerfile I have also

```
ENV AGENT_NAME DockerAgent1
```

When I remove that from my dockerfile the name of the teamcityagent is ip_[number]

How can I register multiple agents in teamcity, that are using the same image in docker, while each has a different teamcity-agent name.

Comment: Why are u tagging `powershell` ?

Comment: Because I am using powershell. But what has that to do with my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give different names to your agent. So use something like below

```
docker run --name DockerAgent1 -e AGENT_NAME=DockerAgent1 <same image id>
docker run --name DockerAgent2 -e AGENT_NAME=DockerAgent2 <same image id>
```

Comment: I did that but when I run two agents. In teamcity I see that the first one get disconnected.

Comment: I did:
docker run --name DockerAgenttest1 -e AGENT_NAME=DockerAgenttest1 -d image
docker run --name DockerAgenttest2 -e AGENT_NAME=DockerAgenttest2 -d image

and now they are connected. Thanks for helping me. Dont know where I could find this information.

Comment: Basically you needed to override the environment variables not the container name. Your `ENV AGENT_NAME DockerAgent1` gave me that hint. So you didn't need documentation, just connecting the dots

Comment: Is docker compose also able to do this? Or should I every time I want to run 3 agents type the command for each agent in powershell?

Comment: See this https://tarunlalwani.com/post/docker-compose-scale-with-dynamic-configuration-part-1/