# How to run multiple containers of docker image with different configuration in it

Tags: python, docker

I have a `opencv python` project where I am reading `rtsp` url from `config.json` and based on that I am doing some logic. Now I have created a docker image for this and its container runs fine.

Now I need to run 2 containers of the same docker image but both of the containers will use different rtsp url which means I need to have 2 config files in the project. But the python docker image I have uses only 1 config.json

Is there any way during run time I can provide `config1.json` `config2.json` respectively to both the containers and for each container it acts like `config.json`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Docker containers, same image, different config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980547/multiple-docker-containers-same-image-different-config)

Comment: @taha Yes it solves my question.